# How to convert an integer to float with zeros at the end in erlang?

Tags: erlang

How can I convert a integer to float in erlang.

```
>N = 10000000.
>float(N).
1.0e7
```

But I'm expecting the result like this:

```
10000000.0
```

But it works like this:

```
>N1 = 10000002.
> float(N1).    
10000002.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> 1.0e7 =:= 10000000.0.
true
```

Those numbers are definitely the same.
I think you are just confused about the *display* of `N` in the Shell.

Comment: Of course they are same. But I'm displaying that on the template. which is the bug for the client. I'll have to either need to convert to string to display on template. and again need to convert to float while storing to database.

Comment: Then you have a bug *displaying* floats. Yet you have shown no code that displays floats. What do you use as float2str? What you can do is use [io_lib:format/2](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/io_lib.html?i=0&search=io_lib:format#format/2) with [io:format/2's options](http://erldocs.com/17.0-rc1/stdlib/io.html?i=4&search=io:format#format/3) in order to stringify your floats the way you want.

Comment: @fenolip: Okay, I'll check